# Is it possible to git rebase and skip all conflicts?

Tags: git

Is it possible to git rebase without having to manually call `git rebase --skip` for each individual conflict. Can you just call something like `git rebase --skip all`?

Comment: It's rarely appropriate to just *skip* a conflict: conflicts need to be resolved, not skipped. In a few rare cases you might know in advance that this particular conflict's resolution is "drop the original commit entirely" but because this is so rare, there is nothing built in to do that.

Comment: @torek yeah, but `git rebase --abort` is buggy on sparse checkouts. It's quicker and safer to just skip all the conflicts then sort the mess out.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you could try with a bash while:

```
while [ true ]; do git rebase --skip; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; done
```

So, you will be cycling issuing `git rebase --skip` every single time that git stops with a problem.... when it *does not* end with a problem (in which case I assume it would have an exit code of 0), then the while will break